# Graduating from a terrible department in an ok University vs. a fantastic department in an obscure university

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I'm a PhD student in a terrible department in my field, in an overall ok university, and have just applied to another program (also PhD) in a very new but fantastic department (research-wise at least -- they *just* had a load of new world-class hires most of whom know me and my work; expected ranking in the field is top 5 in the world, by the next year) but in a very obscure university. I'm wondering if I should go if I get admitted, at least considering the future job market prospects. Would the obscurity of the university make so much difference even if the department is going to be highly valued?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest that instead of worrying about rankings you think about the quality of your own work and whether your advisor is helpful and has enough clout to get you on your way. The rest of the department means little.

Comment: The answers [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/60199/which-ranking-is-more-meaningful-for-post-doc-students) may be relevant.

Comment: Also, you may want to separate the two questions -- we can't say anything meaningful about the situation at your current department based on what you wrote here, so I would remove the second paragraph and create a second post about that if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, for your future academic career, prestige of University as a whole is less important than prestige of department, and that is less important than prestige of advisor. And all of that is tempered by the strenth of reference letters you will obtain, and by the directly observable quality of your work. (By the latter, I mean how good your dissertation / publications are, the specifics of this highly dependent on your field).

Also worth saying, however, is that if you leave academia, the rank order of those factors for getting a good nonacademic job is generally reversed. (Ph.D. students generally don't like seriously thinking about nonacademic career prospects since their goal is an academic career, but in many disciplines the proportion who will go on to nonacademic careers is shockingly high, so you should at least contemplate this.)

In your instance, I would add 2 factors to consideration.

1. It's clear you aren't happy where you are now, and feel you would be happy somewhere else. Life is too short to deliberately choose an unhappy road to a (good) Ph.D. if a happier one is or becomes available to you.
2. "The grass is always greener on the other side of the fence." Don't overindex on the negatives of what you are experiencing now, and compare that with only expected positives of what your potential alternative is. In particular, look hard in the mirror: what have *you* learnt to do differently if you go to a new place, and do you have a tendency in life to frequently hit the restart button -- especially multiple times in a row? (Bluntness alert!) Everyone in academia develops pattern recognition for smart people who somehow serially fail to deploy, and are always restarting, but the restart only leads to another restart later on. We don't know you, so don't treat this as an implied accusation that this applies to you  -- but do look in the mirror to consider whether this is the case, and if so, what you need to do differently to not have to restart again.

With all that, best wishes, and do what (with self-reflection) feels right!

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! I will contemplate the situation more thoroughly.